# Spliting hash key containing of arrays to another keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key

I have a problem with my ruby script. I don't know how to convert a hash

```
g = { ["name1", "name2"] => [{ "email" => "adam@adam.pl" }], 
      ["name3", "name4"] => [{ "email" => "ewa@ewa.pl" }], 
      ["name5", "name6", "name7", "name8"] => [{ "email" => "ala@ala.pl" }] }
```

to a hash:

```
x = { "name1" => [{ "email" => "adam@adam.pl" }],
      "name2" => [{ "email" => "adam@adam.pl" }],
      "name3" => [{ "email" => "ewa@ewa.pl" }],
      "name4" => [{ "email" => "ewa@ewa.pl" }],
      "name5" => [{ "email" => "ala@ala.pl" }],
      "name6" => [{ "email" => "ala@ala.pl" }],
      "name7" => [{ "email" => "ala@ala.pl" }],
      "name8" => [{ "email" => "ala@ala.pl" }] }
```

I need to split the keys e.g. `["name1", "name2"]` and put them as a keys of its value `"name1" => [{ "email" => "adam@adam.pl" }], "name2" => [{ "email" => "adam@adam.pl" }]`.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, I tried to split key's array by the numebr of elements, but I don't know how to put the value as a value of all new keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is you can try something like it to get the result like

```
h = Hash[*g.map { |keys, value| keys.map {|key| [key,value]} }.flatten]
```

Which gives us a Hash

```
{ "name1" => { "email" => "adam@adam.pl" },
  "name2" => { "email" => "adam@adam.pl" },
  "name3" => { "email" => "ewa@ewa.pl" },
  "name4" => { "email" => "ewa@ewa.pl" },
  "name5" => { "email" => "ala@ala.pl" },
  "name6" => { "email" => "ala@ala.pl" },
  "name7" => { "email" => "ala@ala.pl" },
  "name8" => { "email" => "ala@ala.pl" } }
```

In the above value is also hash format not in array. If its not required then this can work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
g.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), obj|
  k.each { |e| obj[e] = v }
end
```

Performance comparison with other solution:

```
#                                           user     system      total        real
# each_with_object...
# separate_keys1(1_000_000 times):      9.765000   0.000000   9.765000 (  9.908535)
# Hash[]...
# separate_keys2(1_000_000 times):     16.505000   0.016000  16.521000 ( 16.725911)
```